# Avoid Repeated Function call in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, function

I know this is bad, I just don't know how to re-write it... any help appreciated!

```
DECLARE @i   INT, 
    @var VARCHAR(max) 

SET @i = 0 

WHILE 1 = 1 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO mrs.dbo.nav_worldcheck_results 
              ("counter", 
               "entity no", 
               "entity first name", 
               "entity last name", 
               "entity full name", 
               "worldcheck uid", 
               "worldcheck first name", 
               "worldcheck last name", 
               "worldcheck full name", 
               "percentage match") 
  SELECT TOP(1) [Counter] = @i, 
                EN.[entity no_], 
                EN.[name 2], 
                EN.[name], 
                EN.[name 2] + ' ' + EN.[name]          AS EntityName, 
                SM.uid                                 AS WorldCheckID, 
                SM.[first name], 
                SM.[last name], 
                SM.[first name] + ' ' + SM.[last name] AS WorldCheckName, 
                dbo.Fn_calculatejarowinkler(EN.[name 2] + ' ' + EN.[name], 
                SM.[first name] + ' ' + SM.[last name]) 
  FROM   [NAV_LIVE].dbo.[entitytable$entity] AS EN 
         CROSS JOIN [NAV_LIVE].dbo.[worldcheck master] AS SM 
  WHERE  ( EN.inactive = 0 ) 
         AND dbo.Fn_calculatejarowinkler(EN.[name 2] + ' ' + EN.[name], 
                 SM.[first name] + ' ' + SM.[last name]) >= .75 
         AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                        FROM   mrs.dbo.nav_worldcheck_results AS WCR 
                        WHERE  EN.[entity no_] = WCR.[entity no] 
                               AND WCR.[worldcheck uid] = SM.uid) 

  SET @i = @i + 1 
END
```

I want to avoid the repeated function call in the where statement and I've tried assigning all as variables and then processing but I fall into the trap of you can't mix sets with data retrieval and my poor little brain is in Friday mode! :o/

Comment: Are you sure that a cross cartesian join is really what this query is supposed to be doing?  It almost always never is..

Comment: I dunno, I've got to the stage of clutching at straws... what it is supposed to do is find a fuzzy match between our Entity (people) table and worldchecks criminal database. So as you can imagine the worldcheck data is a bit of a monster... it works... but it is horribly slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can optimize out your function call. Potentially you could consider pre computing this value if the query needs to be run regularly and the data doesn't change.

I recommend that you read a little more about joins and determine if a cross cartesian is really necessary in your case(most of the time you actually want an inner join). http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

You should really also consult with your DBAs to ensure you are operating on Indexed columns or see if they can add indexes to speed things up.

I would also look into learning about your databases(I assume MSSQL) query tuning capabilities. Notably the explain plan can tell you in more depth what your query is actually doing and where you could optimize.

Although its impossible to know how the query is being optimized beforehand, in general NOT EXISTS and EXISTS filters can be horribly inefficient.  Especially if the filter on the not exists query returns more than one row or if it operates on non indexed columns.  Either way I recommend `select 1` instead of `select *` since reducing the number of columsn selected is an easy optimization.

Comment: Thanks Deadron. It's a horrible query as the only link between the two tables is the fuzzy match and you'd want to return anything that is close enough to worry about. I can probably use the CLR functions in SQL 2012 which will give me a slight performance benefit and your right, I could lose the Exists if I thought about it a bit more. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry I couldnt help more. Its really difficult to optimize SQL without the table schemas and a generated explain plan. Along with an accurate description of what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this case SqlServer query processor (looks like you use SqlServer?) does not necessarily call `dbo.Fn_calculatejarowinkler` function twice for every returned row (first time in select part and second time in the where clause) as you may think. If function is deterministic, likely it does not doing it.

You may rewrite your statement:

```
SELECT
    ...
    dbo.Fn_calculatejarowinkler(EN.[name 2] + ' ' + EN.[name], 
            SM.[first name] + ' ' + SM.[last name])
    ...
FROM ... AS EN
    CROSS JOIN ... AS SM
WHERE
    ...
    AND dbo.Fn_calculatejarowinkler(EN.[name 2] + ' ' + EN.[name], 
                 SM.[first name] + ' ' + SM.[last name]) >= .75
    ...
```

in the following way:

```
SELECT
    ...
    F.Value,
    ...
FROM ... AS EN
    CROSS JOIN ... AS SM
    CROSS APPLY (
        select dbo.Fn_calculatejarowinkler(EN.[name 2] + ' ' + EN.[name], 
            SM.[first name] + ' ' + SM.[last name])
    ) F(Value)
WHERE
    ...
    AND F.Value >= .75
    ...
```

but unlikely you will gain in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for looking and taking the time to reply.

I've actually done as Deadron suggested and used a mix of inner join using soundex as the relationship rather than the cross join.

I've also added in the use of "difference" into the where clause rather than my Jaro function and performance has improved dramatically and it's returning hits that would be close enough to worry about.

Thanks again!